# How to run System Android App on system user

Tags: android, embedded-linux, android-source

I am Working on Android System app, that means I signed it with the platform key and I pushed it into "**/system/priv-app**", but when I check it with "**adb shell ps**" I found the user is "**u0_a40"** not "**system**"

Who can explain me what happen and what can I do to run the app with the system user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AndroidManifest.xml` needs to specify that your app is supposed to run as `system` user:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.mysystemapp"
          android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"
          coreApp="true">
```

For completeness sake, if you want to compile your system app as part of the AOSP build process via an `Android.mk` file, you need to put this in the `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
```

This ensures that the app ends up in `/system/priv-app` and is signed by the platform key.

Comment: It is works, I forget to add sharedUserId in Manifest, thank you @Erlkoenig

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to add coreApp="true" to the manifest, as it is required when the app need to run in certain boot mode, such as "safe mode". the sharedUserId and the platform certificate will be enough.

Comment: I agree with you, I didn't use it.